# AddClass onClick won't work

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, web

I'm having some problems getting some simple jQuery to work; I'm trying to add a class called `fadeInLeft` to my `body` element on click. Here's the code:

```
$('.contact-button').click(function() {
    $('body').addClass('fadeInLeft')
});
```

HTML (from comment left by OP, below):

```
<div id="contact" class="bounceInRight animated four">
    <a href="#" class="contact-button"> Say Hello </a>
</div><!--End of contact-->
```

`contact-button` is the class of the link, `fadeInLeft` is the class I want to add when the link is clicked. Any idea why this would not work ?

Comment: Is there an element on the page with class `contact-button`?

Comment: @davidThomas Yup it is.

Comment: @sergio Yes I am. I'm trying to get the body to fadeout on click.

Comment: @BryanDowning Yes there is. <a href="#" class="contact-button"> Say Hello </a>

Comment: @DavidThomas <div id="contact" class="bounceInRight animated four">
                        <a href="#" class="contact-button"> Say Hello </a>
                    </div><!--End of contact-->

Comment: @QTaylor It works ... http://jsfiddle.net/CFVL4/ There must be an issue elsewhere - perhaps the class you're adding just isn't having the effect you're expecting?

Comment: @QTaylor, if you want a fade out "effect" you need something else like jQuery fadeout. Just changing class will be a blackout, not a fadeout.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.contact-button').click(function() {
       $('body').addClass('fadeInLeft')
    });
});
```

to ensure the function binds after the page has loaded.  it could be trying to bind the click event to an object that does not yet exist

Comment: or use .on $(document).on('click','.contact-button',function(){ ...

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are looking for a **fadeout effect** (from what I read in your comments), try this:

```
$('.contact-button').click(function() {
    $('body').fadeOut("slow", function() {
       $('body').addClass('fadeInLeft')
    });     
});
```

This requires jQuery.
**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zhxt4/)**